# How does Linux Mint relate to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

How Linux Mint relate to Ubuntu?

As I see both OS use .deb packages, but is it possible to install e.g. MongoDB on Linux Mint using instructions for Ubuntu OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux Mint is very, very close to Ubuntu. Mint is made by modifying Ubuntu just like Ubuntu is made by Modifying Debian. However, Ubuntu has diverged considerably for Debian (the Debian repositories are not compatible with Ubuntu nor the Ubuntu ones with Debian). Mint, on the other hand, is very similar to Ubuntu. The Mint developers have added some extra tools and tweaked the interface a little, but the differences are not major. Mint can use Ubuntu repositories (including ppas) with no problem.

So yes, any instructions you find for Ubuntu are almost certain to be applicable to Mint as well.